# pass onChange func props doesn't work material-ui-picker react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

It is necessary to pass from the child component of the props it is a change, but the validation of the piker disappeared and the state does not change

### **My Stateless Component**

```
import { KeyboardDatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";

const Picker = ({dateOnChange,dateOfOrdinance}) => {
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        inputVariant="outlined"
        clearable
        label="От:"
        value={dateOfOrdinance}
        onChange={dateOnChange}
        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start" }}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
}
```

**My parent Component**

```
export default class Case extends Component {  
    state={dateOfOrdinance: new Date()}
    render() {
    return (
        <Picker dateOnChange={(date)=> 
             this.setState({dateOfOrdinance: date}) />
    )
  }
}
```

If I declare it in the parent, then everything will be fine, there will be validation and the state will change

Comment: From where you are getting `dateOfOrdinance` in child component?

Comment: pass it through props

Comment: But your parent component has `<Picker dateOnChange={(date)=> 
             this.setState({dateOfOrdinance: date}) />` which don't pass `dateOfOrdinance `

Comment: oh really not set, ty)

Comment: Another point you should care about -> you should not have several copies of MuiPickersUtilsProvider in your tree. Use it once on the top level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problems in this line,

```
<Picker dateOnChange={(date)=> this.setState({dateOfOrdinance: date}) />
```

You have not passed `dateOfOrdinance` as props here, do this to pass data

```
<Picker dateOfOrdinance={this.state.dateOfOrdinance} dateOnChange={(date)=> this.setState({dateOfOrdinance: date}) />
```